# Error in Atom Editor for Database Connectivity in .env file .Atom cant recognize some files when I import Laravel-8 project

Tags: mysql, laravel, atom-editor

How Do I create database in atom editor. I have also Installed Data Atom but it gives error when I run, but there are errors(connectECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306) in .env file. i have made some words in .env file bold that gives red line error. I think that my atom editor doesnt recognize .env file.

```
APP_NAME  =Laravel
APP_ENV= local
APP_KEY= base64:Dzm/b1rWVV+NZO59PXdZjVgvOCZv7oSoCpFHT3PWPhA=
APP_DEBUG =true
APP_URL= http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL =stack
LOG_LEVEL= debug

DB_CONNECTION= mysql  // This mysql contain red line under it
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel // This laravel contain red line under it
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST= mailhog  // This mailbox contain red line under it
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=  mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY=  "${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=  "${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This package in atom support .env fie.

https://atom.io/packages/language-dotenv